# DocuSIgn eSign Rest API to disable sending signed document as attachment for completed workflow for specific envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

Is there an eSign Rest API available that can be used to disable sending the completed document as an attachment when the workflow is completed for specific envelopes ? I know that there is a settings in the Admin section that can be used to disable sending completed document when the workflow is completed. But this account level setting will work for all the envelopes being sent out from that account. Is there an envelope level eSign Rest API that can be used to achieve the same thing for specific envelopes ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, the Sending account has a setting to determine if completed documents are attached to the "envelope completed" email sent to the recipients.  However, there is nothing in the envelope to override the account setting.

I would recommend using the account setting to prevent the completed documents from being attached to the completion emails (because email attachments are not secure), and instead advice signers to use the prompt at the end of signing to save an account that they can log into to securely download the documents at their leisure. It's also worth noting that if the documents in the envelope are too large, attachment may not take place, making it even more important to use a free signer account to securely access envelope documents.

Answer (score -1):

Are you referring to the completed document being attached and sent to the recipients via email? I'm afraid you can't control this setting. It is individual to the recipient's account and only they can change the behaviour for this